# SQL query with multiple many-to-one joins

Tags: postgresql, join, count, where

I want to select a count of all surveys where the `survey.property.address.city == "Garrison"`. I have the following tables (stripped for your convenience):

```
surveys                 properties             addresses     
----------------        ---------------        ---------
id | property_id        id | address_id        id | city
```

And the failing query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM   surveys s
JOIN   properties p ON s.property_id = p.id
JOIN   addresses a ON p.address_id = a.id
WHERE  a.city = "Garrison"
```

The error message as follows:

```
ERROR:  column "Garrison" does not exist
LINE 5: WHERE addresses.city = "Garrison";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM   surveys s
JOIN   properties p ON s.property_id = p.id
JOIN   addresses a ON p.address_id = a.id
WHERE  a.city = 'Garrison'
```